# Php mail post stays in sending mode

Tags: javascript, php

When i try to send mail with the code the send button stays in "sending" and never changes to "sent". But mail is actuall sent to my mail box... 
You can check in site [secco.uni.me](http://secco.uni.me)
Thanks.

The html code of main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Sun and Moon Calculations</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="site_icon.png">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"> 
<meta name="description" content="Calculate local sunrise, sunset, moonrise, moonset and moon illumination with a click on map. Learn your time zone. Great tool for photographers and hunters as well as security forces. "> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="secco.css"> 
<link href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2rBJhT2rjQwA3jVKYrbbElkkm525UabU&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="time.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img alt="Under Construction" src="ribbon.png" width="132" height="100" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;">
<script src="moon.js"></script>
<center>
    <h2>Sun and Moon Calculations</h2>
    <div id="bd">
        <div id="gmap"></div>
        <!--Lat: <span id="lat"></span> Lon: <span id="lon"></span><br/>
        Zoom Level: <span id="zoom_level"></span> -->
    <div id="expl"><h5>*Click <span style="color:red">red</span> marker for exact coordinates.
        Center the map, then hit buttons for calculations. Your feedback is valuable...<h5></div>
    </div>
    <div id="form">
    <form name=calc>
        <table border="" cellspacing=5 bordercolor=white frame=void rules=rows>
        <tr>
            <td>Latitude  <td><INPUT size=20 maxLength=10 name=lat>
            <td>RAW Offset<td><INPUT readOnly size=35 maxLength=35 name=rawoffset>
            <td>Moonrise  <td><INPUT readOnly size=20 maxLength=20 name=moonrise>
        <tr>
            <td>Longitude <td><INPUT size=20 maxLength=20 name=lon>
            <td>DST Offset<td><INPUT readOnly size=35 maxLength=35 name=dstoffset>
            <td>Moonset<td><INPUT readOnly size=20 maxLength=20 name=moonset>
        <tr>
            <td>Zoom Level<td><INPUT readOnly size=20 maxLength=20 name=zl>
            <td>Time Zone ID <td><INPUT readOnly size=35 maxLength=35 name=timezoneid>
            <td>Moon Phase<td><INPUT readOnly size=20 maxLength=20 name=moonphase>
        <tr>
            <td>This Day  <td><INPUT readOnly size=20 maxLength=20 name=thisday>
            <td>Time Zone <td><INPUT readOnly size=35 maxLength=35 name=timezone>
        <tr>

        <td>Timestamp <td><INPUT readOnly size=20 maxLength=20 name=timestamp>

        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="setLocation()" value="Set Location">
    <input type="button" onclick="compute()" value="Moon Calculation">
    <input type="button" onclick="sun()" value="Sun Calculation"><br>
</center>

<!-- Feedback mail post section-->
<!-- hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">
    <h2>Send us a Message</h2>

    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
        <br>
        <label for="msg">Enter a Message</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>

        <button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mailpost.js"></script>
<!-- BOTTOM STUFF -->
<div id="bottom">
<script language="JavaScript">
initdate();
var count = "secco";          // Change Your Account?
var type = "war2orc";       // Change Your Counter Image?
var digits = "7";          // Change The Amount of Digits on Your Counter?
var prog = "hit";          // Change to Either hit/unique?
var statslink = "no";    // provide statistical link in counter yes/no?
var sitelink = "yes";     // provide link back to our site;~) yes/no?
var cntvisible = "yes"; // do you want counter visible yes/no?
</script>
<!-- START DO NOT TAMPER WITH ANYTHING ELSE BELOW THIS LINE FOR YOUR WEBTV & UNIX VISITORS -->
<a href="http://jquery.com"><img src="jquery-logo.png" width="70" height="15" style="position: relative;width:95% text-align:left;top:3px; left:60px;"/></a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com"><img src="google-maps-api-v3.png" width="70" height="15" style="position: relative;width:95% text-align:left;top:3px; left:-90px;"/></a>
<a class = "modalbox" href="#inline"><img src="icon_mailto.gif" style="position: relative;width:95% text-align:right;top:3px; left:-8px;"/></a>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://005.free-counters.co.uk/count-072.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://www.free-counters.co.uk" target="_blank">
<img  src="http://005.free-counters.co.uk/count-072.pl?count=secco&cntvisible=no&mode=noscript" style="position: absolute;" alt="Free Counters" title="Free Counters" border="0">
</a>The following text will not be seen after you upload your website,
please keep it in order to retain your counter functionality 
<br><a href="http://www.free-counters.co.uk/trackers/" target="_blank">Trackers</a><br> <a href="http://www.free-counters.co.uk/help/counter/" target="_blank">Counter Help</a><br>
</noscript>
<!-- END DO NOT TAMPER WITH ANYTHING ELSE ABOVE THIS LINE FOR YOUR WEBTV & UNIX VISITORS -->
</div>
</CENTER>        
</body>
</html>
```

My mailpost.js file:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox();
        $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


        $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
            var msglen    = msgval.length;
            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(msglen < 4) {
                $("#msg").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(msglen >= 4){
                $("#msg").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
                // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmessage.php',
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

And sendmessage.php file

```
<?php
$sendto   = "mail@hotmail.com";
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$content  = nl2br($_POST['msg']);

$subject  = "New Feedback Message";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New User Feedback</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

Comment: There is no button in your code above. You're going to have to provide more information if you want help.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Sorry my first post here... The other js code was added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Code

```
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmessage.php',
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == 1) {
                            $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I changed the true and false echo responses to 0 and 1. 
I suppose there is a problem about js code about fetching the return from php code. Anyway the code runs as it is supposed to. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You set the text to "sending..." with this:

```
$("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");
```

But you never set it to anything else after that. So, it stays put. If you want to change it, you can add a line to your success function, like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data == "true") {
        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
        });
        $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sent!</em>"); // This is the line to add.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
```

to

```
if(mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
```

Additionally, I recommend using `die("true");` or removing the closing PHP tag otherwise you risk having a confusing new line at the end of the file that can potentially produce undesired results.

Comment: This does not address the question; the OP's question is not about how to use PHP `mail()`, but about the javascript effects after the mail is sent.

Comment: @EdCottrell Either way silencing warnings like that can cause a significant degrade in performance.

Comment: That's fine, but that doesn't make this an answer -- it should be a comment.

Comment: @EdCottrell I know, it's just that I need 50 rep to post a comment. A dumb restriction IMO.